# Add ProcessInstanceWorkitem tab

Tags: approval-process, configuration, tab

By clicking on Step 1 link in Approval History related list, you can access ProcessInstanceWorkitem item which show all user's pending request by modifying the URL. Is there a way to add a tab instead ? If not, what's the best way to showcase all request across all object ?